# Ternary association - multiplicity between two classes

Tags: uml

Suppose I have the following diagram (I can't post images directly) - a ternary association between classes A, B, C

[image]

What should be added to this diagram to ensure that objects of class A can be associated with a maximum of 50 B objects?

Comment: Since you don't mention C, your constraint does not refer to the ternary association, but seems to refer to a binary association between A and B. So, what do you really mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it that way. You must draw association lines between each class and specify the cardinality.

Comment: I need to draw another line between A and B and specify it there? But I don't want to ADD a new association, but just impose a restriction on this ternary association. BTW: I didn't say how I want to do that, so you don't know if I can do it that way or not :) Oh, and I can't get rid of this ternary association. It has to be there.

Comment: You must draw three lines (associations), or not specify the cardinality. It has no sense to have a n-ary association and having specific cardinality for each of the associations.

Comment: First of all, I can't remove anything from that diagram. I can only add new associations, symbols, anything... but not remove. So the question is, given this particular diagram, how to add something to it to make sure no more than 50 B objects will be associated with a given A object?

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach a constraint to the connector. It looks like a note where the constraint is written in curly brackets.

```
{ max. 50 objects can be associated }
```

You could also write that as OCL - or simply use plain text as above.